# Find the Level of Sections in XML Structured Document - perl

Tags: xml, perl

Find the Level of Sections in XML Structured Document - perl
Input:

```xml
<section>
   <para>...level 1</para>
   <para>...level 1</para>
   <para>...level 1</para>
   <section>
      <para>...level 2</para>
      <para>...level 2</para>
      <section>
         <para>...level 3</para>
         <para>...level 3</para>
         <para>...level 3</para>
      </section>
      <para>...level 2</para>
   </section>
   <section>
      <para>...level 2</para>
      <para>...level 2</para>
      <para>...level 2</para>
   </section>
</section>
<section>
   <para>...level 1</para>
   <para>...level 1</para>
   <para>...level 1</para>
   <section>
      <para>...level 2</para>
      <para>...level 2</para>
      <para>...level 2</para>
   </section>
   <section>
      <para>...level 2</para>
      <para>...level 2</para>
      <para>...level 2</para>
   </section>
</section>
```

I need to fetch all the section level elements and insert the value based on the levels. And the desired output like as follows:

```
<section1>
<para>...level 1</para>
<para>...level 1</para>
<para>...level 1</para>
   <section2>
   <para>...level 2</para>
   <para>...level 2</para>
      <section3>
      <para>...level 3</para>
      <para>...level 3</para>
      <para>...level 3</para>
      </section3>
   <para>...level 2</para>
   </section2>
   <section2>
   <para>...level 2</para>
   <para>...level 2</para>
   <para>...level 2</para>
   </section2>
</section1>
<section1>
<para>...level 1</para>
<para>...level 1</para>
<para>...level 1</para>
   <section2>
   <para>...level 2</para>
   <para>...level 2</para>
   <para>...level 2</para>
   </section2>
   <section2>
   <para>...level 2</para>
   <para>...level 2</para>
   <para>...level 2</para>
   </section2>
</section1>
```

First try:

```
foreach my $lines ( @splitCnt ) {

    if ( $lines =~ m/<section\s+/g ) {
        $opn++;
        $lines =~ s/<section\s+/<section$opn /i;
        $cls = $opn;
        $opn++;
    }
    elsif ( $lines =~ m/<\/section>/g ) {
        $opn = $opn - 1;
        $lines =~ s/<\/section>/<\/section$opn>/i;
    }

    $all_lines .= "$lines\n";
}
```

Second Try:

```
my ( $pre1, $match1, $post1 ) = "";

while ( $incnt =~ m/<section\s+[^>]*>/g ) {

    $pre1   = $`;
    $match1 = $&;
    $post1  = $';
    my $Opn = '1';
    my $Cls = "";

    $match1 =~ s/<section\s+/<section$Opn /gi;

    if ( $post1 =~ m/<section\s+/i ) {
        $Opn++;
        $post1 =~ s/<section\s+/<section$Opn /;
        $Opn = $Cls;
    }
    elsif ( $post1 =~ m/<\/section>/i ) {
        $post1 =~ s/<\/section/<\/section$Cls/;
    }

    $pre1 .= $match1;
    $incnt = $post1;

    print "$pre1\n";
    system 'pause';
}

if ( length $pre1 ) {
    $incnt = $pre1 . $post1;
}
```

Anyone could help on this one...

Comment: The text nodes that were _level3_ in the input are _level2_ in the ouput. Is that on purpose?

Comment: This smells like an XY problem. Why are you trying to rename the 'levels' like this? Also - use a parser.

Comment: Use an XML parser: [XML::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple)

Comment: Use an XML Parser, but please, don't use `XML::Simple` - even the docs call it deprecated.

Comment: [The use of `XML::Simple` module in new code is discouraged.](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple#STATUS-OF-THIS-MODULE)

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche: I am not used any xml modules like XML... any examples...?

Comment: I like `XML::Twig`. `XML::LibXML` has a good reputation too.

Comment: @simbabque: I have changed.... Its my typo issues.

Comment: @ssr1012 if you had looked at the link I gave you, you'd see examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seriously - don't use regular expresssions for XML. It's bad news. There's a bunch of perfectly valid things you can do with XML that break regular expressions - so what you get is broken XML, and brittle code that may well break horribly one day,  and no one will know quite why.

Use a parser. Personally - I like [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::Twig)

It's quite easy to take and rename tags as you ask:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

sub process_section {
    my ( $section, $depth ) = @_;
    $depth++;
    $section->set_tag("section$depth");
    foreach my $subsection ( $section->children('section') ) {
        process_section( $subsection, $depth );
    }
}

my $twig = XML::Twig->new( 'pretty_print' => 'indented_a' );
$twig->parsefile ( 'your_file.xml' ); 

foreach my $section ( $twig->findnodes('section') ) {
    process_section( $section, 0 );
}

$twig->print;
```

I would also point out though - your initial question sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/270186). What are you trying to accomplish? It's often undesirable to do this sort of operation - changing tags based on hierarchy, because then ... well, then you *couldn't* do what I've just done - iterate recursively through the data structure.

Comment: Based on the section hierarchy, <?xmltex \pgtag{\HIfollowedHII}?>|<?xmltex \pgtag{\HIIfollowedHIII}?>|<?xmltex \pgtag{\HIIIfollowedHIV}?> tags should be inserted.

And also I am not aware of the XML::Parser and I haven't used too. Hence forth I will try to do by the way modules. Thanks a lot...

Comment: Inserting tags is a different beast to _changing_ existing ones.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variant using the [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) module. It simply finds all the `section` elements and caclulates their hierarchy by counting the number of slashes in the XPath expression to reach them

However, as others have said, this is a strange thing to want to do, and it very much sounds like its a bad solution to a different problem. If you explained the complete problem then we could help you a lot better

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(IO => \*DATA);

for my $section ( $doc->findnodes('//section') ) {
    my $n = $section->nodePath =~ tr|/|| - 1;
    $section->setNodeName("section$n");
}

print $doc;

__DATA__
<root>
    <section>
        <para>...level 1</para>
        <para>...level 1</para>
        <para>...level 1</para>
        <section>
            <para>...level 2</para>
            <para>...level 2</para>
            <section>
                <para>...level 3</para>
                <para>...level 3</para>
                <para>...level 3</para>
            </section>
            <para>...level 2</para>
        </section>
        <section>
            <para>...level 2</para>
            <para>...level 2</para>
            <para>...level 2</para>
        </section>
    </section>
    <section>
        <para>...level 1</para>
        <para>...level 1</para>
        <para>...level 1</para>
        <section>
            <para>...level 2</para>
            <para>...level 2</para>
            <para>...level 2</para>
        </section>
        <section>
            <para>...level 2</para>
            <para>...level 2</para>
            <para>...level 2</para>
        </section>
    </section>
</root>
```

#### output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <section1>
        <para>...level 1</para>
        <para>...level 1</para>
        <para>...level 1</para>
        <section2>
            <para>...level 2</para>
            <para>...level 2</para>
            <section3>
                <para>...level 3</para>
                <para>...level 3</para>
                <para>...level 3</para>
            </section3>
            <para>...level 2</para>
        </section2>
        <section2>
            <para>...level 2</para>
            <para>...level 2</para>
            <para>...level 2</para>
        </section2>
    </section1>
    <section1>
        <para>...level 1</para>
        <para>...level 1</para>
        <para>...level 1</para>
        <section2>
            <para>...level 2</para>
            <para>...level 2</para>
            <para>...level 2</para>
        </section2>
        <section2>
            <para>...level 2</para>
            <para>...level 2</para>
            <para>...level 2</para>
        </section2>
    </section1>
</root>
```